# Googlemap v3 reverse geocoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

using googlemap v3 reverse geocoding samplesource make this source

```
var map;
        var geocoder;
        var marker;
        function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom : 14,
                center : new google.maps.LatLng(30, 30)
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                    mapOptions);
        }

        function codeLatLng() {
              var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(30, 30);
              alert("call codeLatLng() 1");
              geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                  alert("call codeLatLng() 2");
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  if (results[1]) {
                    map.setZoom(11);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map
                    });
                    infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                  } else {
                    alert('No results found');
                  }
                } else {
                  alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                }
              });
            }


        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        codeLatLng();
```

i call function codeLatLng(); last line on code

so call function codeLatLng() and alert message "call codeLatLng() 1

but doesn't call "call codeLatLng() 2" and code doesn't work

what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Any messages in the error console?

Comment: no console is clean no error

Comment: I'd try to take some code out of the data-handling function and leave just the alert. Also, I would place another alert after the data-handling function, but still in the codeLatLng() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is wrong in my code?

Your are executing codeLatLng before your map and the geocoder variable are initialized (initialize runs when the DOM has finished loading, codeLatLng runs immediately).

This would work better:

```
    var map;
    var geocoder;
    var marker;
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom : 14,
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(30, 30)
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);

        // map and geocoder initialized
        codeLatLng();
    }

    function codeLatLng() {
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(30, 30);
          alert("call codeLatLng() 1");
          geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
              alert("call codeLatLng() 2");
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if (results[1]) {
                map.setZoom(11);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map
                });
                infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
              } else {
                alert('No results found');
              }
            } else {
              alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
          });
        }


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: thanks i thought geocoder initial in  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

Comment: the geocoder is initialize in the onload function.  But that doesn't run until the page has loaded, after codeLatLng ran in your original code.